# Por que nas declarações de classes no Python devemos estender object?

Tags: python, orientação-a-objetos, classes

No `Python`, quando declaramos uma classe, estendemos `object`.

```
class StackExchange(object):
    def __init__(self):
        pass
```

Não sei se eu estou enganado, mas tive impressão que em algumas versões isso seja obrigatório; e já em outras, não.

Por que devemos passar `object` como parâmetro? Isso faz parte de alguma convenção?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Primeiro, você não está passando parâmetro algum, a sintaxe parece remeter a isso mas é apenas a forma do Python de indicar qual é a classe que você está herdando.

Em determinado momento (Python 2.2 e 2.3) houve uma mudança no modelo que a linguagem implementa as hierarquias chamado de "[novo estilo](https://www.python.org/doc/newstyle/) de orientação a objeto". Desta forma Python passou adotar um modelo já adotado por algumas outras linguagens, em que todos os objetos devem herdar de uma raiz única que garante a existência de determinados membros em todos os objetos. Esses membros existem na classe `object`, portanto esta classe deve ser sempre herdada direta ou indiretamente - quando herda de outra classe que já está herdando a `object`.

Assim unifica a tipagem, o que é um grande facilitador tratando os tipos *built-in* de forma uniforme.

Algumas linguagens até fazem isto de forma automática, mas além de exigir compatibilidade como estilo antigo ou clássico, o jeito pitônico de codificar é sendo explícito (eu acho isso incoerente com a tipagem dinâmica, mas *whatever*), então só olhando este ponto é coerente ter que declarar a herança em todos os casos.

Claro que ainda é possível usar o estilo antigo, mas diversos recursos mais novos não funcionarão porque eles esperam contar com estes membros nas classes.

No Python 3.x só o novo estilo deve ser usado. Em geral, não há mais problemas de *não-declaração* no `object`, já que ele se tornou implícito (esquisito, né?). Entretanto, é recomendado que o faça não só para melhorar a legibilidade, mas para facilitar um *downgrade* do código usado.

A mudança trouxe o [`super()`](https://docs.python.org/3.9/library/functions.html#super), os [descritores](https://docs.python.org/3.9/howto/descriptor.html) e [`__slots__`](https://docs.python.org/3.9/reference/datamodel.html#slots). Além disto houve uma mudança na forma de [resolução de métodos](https://www.python.org/download/releases/2.3/mro/).

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Python/Conceptual.md).

Answer (score 13):

Não é obrigatório, mas é recomendado, e o comportamento é diferente no Python 2 e no 3.

Segundo [essa documentação](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#new-style-and-classic-classes), até a versão 2.1 o conceito de classe (`class`) era diferente do conceito de tipo (`type`), de modo que `x.__class__` retornava a classe de `x` mas `type(x)` sempre retornava `<type 'instance'>`. A partir do 2.2 esses conceitos foram unificados, de modo que uma classe *"new-style"* é simplesmente um tipo definido pelo usuário, e ambos `x.__class__` e `type(x)` retornam a mesma coisa* - a classe de `x`. O motivo citado foi:

> A maior motivação para introduzir classes *new-style* é para promover a unificação de um modelo de objeto com um meta-modelo completo. Também tem alguns benefícios práticos, como a habilidade de criar subclasses da maioria dos tipos *built-in*, ou a introdução de *"descriptors"*, que permitem propriedades computadas.

Por compatibilidade, as classes *"old-style"* continaram a ser suportadas no Python 2, e o padrão quando se usa:

```
class Foo:
```

é a criação de uma classe *old-style*, enquanto quando se usa:

```
class Foo(object):
```

se cria uma classe *new-style* que herda explicitamente de `object`. Há pouca razão para se criar classes *old-style* (e alguns benefícios em se usar a outra), de modo que o recomendado é sempre usar a segunda sintaxe.

No Python 3, não existem mais classes *old-style*, todas as classes são *new-style* por padrão. Por isso tanto faz se você usa uma ou outra sintaxe, o resultado será o mesmo. Mas por uma questão de consistência, por assim dizer, recomenda-se que ainda assim seja usada a segunda sintaxe - que deixa mais explícito de qual outra(s) classe(s) essa nova classe está herdando.

Algumas diferenças práticas entre as classes *old-style* e *new-style*:

- As novas permitem o uso do `super`, para acessar membros das superclasses diretamente;
- As novas permitem o uso de `__slots__`, quando não se quer uma classe "aberta" - que aceite novos campos ou que campos sejam deletados - mas sim uma com campos bem definidos e fixos;
- As novas não podem ser lançadas, a menos que herdem de `Exception`;
- A ordem de resolução de métodos é diferente, quando há herança múltipla envolvida (i.e. qual superclasse é visitada primeiro, quando o método não existe na própria classe).

<sup>[Fonte](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19950198/520779)</sup>

---

* A menos é claro que a classe/objeto redefinam `__class__`, mas isso já é outra história...