# Quando devo usar __init__ em funções dentro de classes?

Tags: python, orientação-a-objetos, classes, objetos, construtor

Pelo livro que estou estudando, em alguns momentos o autor utiliza `__init__` como sendo uma primeira função de uma classe. Esta função (e outras) sempre possuem `self` como uma das variáveis (coisa que também ainda não compreendi o porquê). Quando devo (e por quê) utilizar funções `__init__` dentro de (algumas) classes?

Quando crio uma classe parental ou até mesmo uma classe que não terá relações de hierarquia entre ela e outras classes, sou obrigado a nomeá-la como:

```
class Batata(object):
```

Esse `object` é obrigatório em algum momento? Se sim, quando?

Comment: Separe em duas perguntas. Aqui mantemos as coisas organizadas. Cada pergunta deve ter apenas uma pergunta. A não ser que fosse completamente relacionada, o que não é o caso. São assuntos da mesma área mas distintos.

Comment: Na verdade nem precisa, a pergunta já foi respondida em outro lugar. Veja a resposta.

Comment: Ok. Obrigado pela dica. Vou ser mais cuidadoso na próxima pergunta.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Você tem razão. OOP é mais complicado do que parece. A maioria das pessoas aprendem errado e morrem fazendo errado. Eu comecei apender nos anos 80 e até hoje tenho dúvidas se estou fazendo certo. OOP mal feito pode ser pior que outro paradigma bem feito.

Nesse caso específico não tem muita dificuldade. Esse é o [construtor de objetos](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/73530/101). Ele é usado para inicializar o objeto quando vai criar uma instância daquela classe. É um jeito esquisito de fazer isto, mas é o jeito Python.

O `self` é um parâmetro obrigatório que receberá a instância criada. Ao contrário de muitas linguagens, ele deve ser explícito. E também ao contrário de muitas linguagem que criam o objeto durante o construtor, Python cria o objeto e passa ele para o construtor complementar com as primeiras ações necessárias quando ele é construído.

Exemplo:

```
class Point:
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y

x = Point(1, 2)
print(x.x)
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/rUFTbv). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/join/qlgwzbpm-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Python/OOP/ClassExample.py).

[Documentação](https://docs.python.org/3.6/tutorial/classes.html).

A segunda parte da pergunta já foi [respondida aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/53037/101).