# Qual a diferença entre classes inicializadas com (e sem) __init___

Tags: python, python-3.x, classes, construtor

Sou iniciante em Python e queria entender uma diferença.
As duas classes abaixo produzem exatamente o mesmo resultado e as variáveis ficam públicas da mesma forma em ambas as classes:

```
class c():
    t = "abc"
    print (t)
    for a in range (3):
        print (a)

class d():
    def __init__(self):
        self.t = "abc"
        print (self.t)
        self.a = 0
        for self.a in range(0, 3):
            print(self.a)

c1 = c()
d1 = d()
```

Resultado:

```
abc
0
1
2
abc
0
1
2
```

Por que então devo usar o construtor `__init__` se ao final de contas os resultados são os mesmos?

Comment: Isso? https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/109013/101

Comment: @Maniero, eu li estes artigos, mas não entendi ainda o por que de usar `__init__` se no meu exemplo os resultados são os mesmos?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Não são os mesmos. No seu exemplo foi quase que mera coincidência. Basta não instanciar a classe `c` que verá o que acontece.

Isso se dá pelo fato de classes serem apenas um limitador de escopo no Python. Você pode inserir códigos normalmente dentro da classe, não apenas definições de campos e métodos, como ocorrem em outras linguagens. A diferença é que este código executará quando a classe for definida.

```
class c():
    t = "abc"
    print (t)
    for a in range (3):
        print (a)
```

Isso já exibirá no terminal mesmo que a classe não seja instanciada, diferente da classe `d`, que implementa o método inicializador, que terá a lógica executada apenas quando for instanciada.

Você pode utilizar isso para definir compatibilidades com diferentes versões do Python. Digamos que um método possui funcionalidades que variam conforme a versão a ser executada e você pretende manter suporte a ambas, poderia fazer algo como:

```
import sys

class Foo:

  if sys.version_info[0] == 3:
    def something(self):
     return 'Python 3'
  else:
    def something(self):
      return 'Python 2'

foo = Foo()

print(foo.something())
```

<sup>Veja funcionando no [Python 3](https://repl.it/@acwoss/AwareGrippingPagerecognition) e no [Python 2](https://repl.it/@acwoss/KlutzyComfortableUsers)</sup>

Obviamente que não faria algo deste gênero para um método tão simples, mas quando você começa a trabalhar com algumas diferenças mais *drásticas* entre as versões, tal como utilizar o método `__str__` ou `__unicode__`, essa abordagem começa a fazer sentido.

Sem contar a diferença que, quando você define um campo sem associar ao `self`, você estará definindo um atributo de classe, enquanto quando utilizado junto ao `self` será um atributo de instância. Isso fará toda diferença quando o tipo trabalhado for mutável, pois sendo mutável e sendo atributo de classe, uma vez modificado a modificação será refletida em todas as instâncias.

```
class Foo:
    field = []

a = Foo()
a.field.append(1)

print(a.field)  # [1]

b = Foo()

print(b.field)  # [1]
```

<sup>Veja funcionando no [Repl.it](https://repl.it/@acwoss/PleasingMotherlyMultitasking)</sup>

Já, se utilizado dentro de `__init__`, com o `self`, a saída de `b.field` seria `[]`, pois seria uma lista independente de `a.field`, mesmo que sejam instâncias da mesma classe. No seu caso, `c.t` será um atributo de classe enquanto `d.t` será um atributo de instância.

Comment: obrigado. Resumindo, entendi que basicamente no meu exemplo, a classe "c" é executada independente de ser instanciada e a classe "d" será executada apenas quando for instanciada. Mas na prática, os resultados são os mesmos. Mas, tirando a questão da compatibilidade de versões do Python, mantendo-se apenas na versão 3, haveria mais alguma diferença real, exceto o momento em que as classes são inicializadas?

Comment: @RogérioDec essa questão de escopo (atributo de classe ou instância) que adicionei ao final da resposta

Comment: Agora entendi! Atributo de classe x atributo de instância. Muito obrigado pela explicação!